# Taken to error page after firefox exits uncleanly and restores tabs

Tags: bug, status-norepro, firefox

I opened firefox after killing it and when I restored my tabs I was brought to this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/1045241/what-is-a-good-stand-alone-javascript-formatter-for-fixing-missing-semicolons

I clicked refresh and everything was fine - it went back to the page it should have gone to in the first place.

Comment: @m0sa I encountered this as well very recently, and for the first time. I had a bunch of tabs open and all were directed to error pages when they were reopened. (Not sure if it was Chrome or Firefox, however.)

Comment: did your browser also exit uncleanly?

Comment: @m0sa Yes, it had crashed. I believe it was due to the Flash process crashing and bringing the browser down with it. (In which case it must have been Firefox, because in Chrome it would not have brought down the browser.)

Comment: thanks for the info, I'll do my best to reproduce it...